# Exclude individuals that is related by some specific inverse properties

Tags: owl, protege, object-property

I have some individuals A,B,C,D,E, and two properties P1, P2.

```
A P1 B
C P1 D
E P2 C
```

I want to build a Class that only captures A but not C. so I set a Class like,

1. myClass EquivalentTo: (P1 some owl:Thing) and (P1 only owl:Thing)
2. myClass EquivalentTo: (P1 some owl:Thing) and (not inverse P2 some owl:Thing)

but all of those tries failed. How can I differentiate the individual A and C?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> myClass EquivalentTo: (P1 some owl:Thing) and (P1 only owl:Thing)

fails because the class expression is really equivalent to **P1 some Thing**. Since *every* individual is an instance of **Thing**, the right hand side of the intersection really doesn't add anything.

> myClass EquivalentTo: (P1 some owl:Thing) and (not inverse P2 some owl:Thing)

This is actually correct for the description that you gave.  You want individuals that have some value for P1 (good), and that are *not* the P2 value of some other individual.  This is the way to describe that.

I think the issue that you're having is that while while your data set doesn't *contain* any triples of the form

**x P2 A**

there's nothing in the ontology that says that such a thing is impossible.  So you can't be sure that **A** actually has the type **(not inverse P2 some Thing)**.  This phenomenon is known as the open world assumption (OWA).  If you search for that, you'll find some other questions on Stack Overflow about OWA in OWL. See, for instance:

- [Why is this DL-Query not returning any individuals?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16841335/why-is-this-dl-query-not-returning-any-individuals/16844965)
- [Strange query behaviour in OWL!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/842801/strange-query-behaviour-in-owl)

In this case, if you want to say that **A** isn't the P2 value of some other individual, you'd probably have to do it manually, by adding a type to **A** like:

**inverse P2 only owl:Nothing**

Once you do that, you'll get the results you want:

[image: the extra axiom]

[image: protege screenshot]